# How to remove blank spaces from a detail section?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

Hello and greetings to the community.

I have the following report made in Visual Studio 2015 using VB.NET and Crystal Reports:

[image: image1]

Those boxes that I painted in light blue are the white spaces that I want to eliminate. The section that contains this information in Crystal Reports is as follows:

[image: image2]

In that section, I have the following associated function, which only contains the functionality of showing or not the section depending on whether the `TipoDocId` is `NULL`:

```
IF IsNull ({SpCon_CONTA_Rpt_LibroDeInvBalances_Cta14;1.TipoDocId} ) THEN
    true
ELSE
    false
```

I'm sorry to use images, but for this specific problem it's the only way to show the problem.

Thanks in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you simply need to suppress Detail Section 2.

Comment: Yes! This was the solution. Thank you so much.